# Seguridad PHP SESSION con JS y AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Un saludo.

El caso es que estoy preparando una app web con PHP y JS y no me gusta mezclar código HTML en los PHP como se suele hacer al crear ficheros index.php y de ese estilo.

Quiero dejar los ficheros .html y .js por un lado y los .php para la conexión con phpmyadmin

Ahora mi pregunta. Resulta que si creo una seguridad con SESSION en PHP, como lo llamo a través de AJAX, aunque sea de forma síncrona, se ve que el .html carga contenido y algo se ve antes de que se redirija, ya se se redirije en la respuesta del AJAX.

Si hago un fichero .php si funciona, porque la redirección la hago arriba del todo con header, pero con AJAX no me viene como poder hacerlo.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Es posible mantener sesiones usando AJAX con PHP., pero no queda del todo claro tu problema. Sería bueno ver un poco de código para saber cómo manejas los `.html`, `.php` y las redirecciones.

Comment: El problema específico es que cuando cargo directamente la página .html, antes de que detecte que no hay variable de sesión, la página llega a cargar los elementos DOM y se ven antes de echarte. Es un fogonazo, pero se deja ver, y eso es lo que querría evitar.

Comment: Entonces estás encarando mal el proyecto, primero debes pasar por PHP para determinar lo que se va a mostrar y solo entonces cargar el contenido HTML o lo que sea.

Comment: Así a bote pronto se está ocurriendo crear el .html solo con un body vacío. Y si el chequeo de seguridad es correcto añadir los elementos con .append(). Se vería una pantalla blanca